# Libreoffice keeps promoting itself to defaultapplication

Tags: libreoffice, default-programs

Running Jammy 22.04.2 with GNOME Shell 42.5.

I have Libre Office installed (and want to keep it around) but usually use a different Office suit (Softmaker Office 21, if this is relevant).

No idea how often I had to change back my default apps for docx, xlsx & friends to my preference after Libre Office has again claimed that for itself. Not sure, but I guess this happens during updates? Is there a way to make my configuration permanent?

Comment: How do you set these?  (xdg-mime or something else?) My 1st idea would be to make `mimeapps.list` read only but that would require you to make it writable when needed.

Comment: Afaik the standard way is to rightclick on a representative file, open the properties dialog and set it on the "Open with"-tab. (Using German localization, so labels might vary). That's how I usually do it.